# Why Jackson converter does not throw an Exception when a getter is missing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class where there is a `boolean` member variable. When the object is converted to `JSON` by the `Jackson` converter while sending a response, the `boolean` field goes missing.

```
public class SampleClass{
    boolean personal;

    public boolean getPersonal(){
     return this.personal;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

I discovered that the `boolean` **getter** in my case was something like `isPersonal()`. After some efforts it struck me that it could be because of the **getter**. When I changed it to `getPersonal()`, things seemed to be fine.

```
public class SampleClass{
    boolean personal;

    public boolean isPersonal(){
     return this.personal;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Why is it that Jakson did not even log any error if the expected **getter** was missing?

It could have caught my eyes straightaway.

Comment: please add code and update your questions.. :)

Comment: The ObjectMapper needs a flag to throw an error on missing fields

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not